# which kernel version do i have to apply patchwork's patch on?

Tags: linux, kernel, patch

For example, I want to apply

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9726505/

this patch from Patchwork, but It shows errors when applied to my kernel version.

I guess there might be a way to get right version on which i can apply patches.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/716383/), it should be applied on top of v4.11-rc1
Also make sure you apply all related patches in order (I see you linked patch 2 out of 6 make sure you have the first one is already applied)

Comment: I had trouble googling other 5 patches and i managed it by entering the author's patch list https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/LKML/list/?submitter=106071

Comment: Interesting to see Patchwork does not provide any searching